# "com.canonical.indicator.messages" entry missing from dconf-editor; issues with email message indicator

Tags: apt, dbus, indicator-message

On my 12.04.03 system I don't have `com.canonical.indicator.messages`.

Even after

```
sudo apt-get install indicator.messages
```

Mail count and new mail notification seems flaky on 12.04. It used to work after a fresh install, but somehow seems to have gotten corrupted...

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the output of `sudo apt-get install indicator.messages`?

Comment: Seth. thank you for enquiring. The output was fine - showed no errors.

I did try to install unity-webapps on my 12.04 system, and I couldn't get this working (having no desire to move to 12.10).

I think the issue arose when I tried this, and now having purged/removed everything to do with unity-webapps, I once again have a 'blue' mail notification icon.

Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: The package is `indicator-messages`. What is your question again?

Answer (score 1):

The correct name of the package isn't `indicator.messages` but `indicator-messages`:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-messages
```

should fix the issue.